# Two python distributions, sudo picking the wrong one

Tags: python, sudo, python-2.7

I'm back to Linux after an over 10 year abstinence (fool me thinks). And a little rusty in the sys admin department.

I'm faced with an issue with my python distribution. I'm using Python 2.7, but based on the Anaconda flavour. I followed the standard guidance but recently I discovered an issue that I'm not sure how to fix.

Under `sudo`, the standard Python as comes with Ubuntu is provided. Under my user account python points to the Anaconda version:

```
dhk@localhost:~/home/$which python
/opt/anaconda/bin/python
dhk@localhost:~/home/$sudo which python
/usr/bin/python
```

This is an issue as using `sudo pip [anything]` usually acts on the wrong directory, yet I cannot use it without sudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sudoers specifies a `secure_path`:

```
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

This will override your local PATH, thus your virtualenv isn't used. You have a few options:

- Call your python binary explicitly: `sudo /opt/anaconda/bin/python file.py`
- Comment out the `secure_path` line in `/etc/sudoers` (but it's probably there for a reason)
- [Specify `keep_env` for this specific command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13240/etc-sudoers-specify-env-keep-for-one-command-only) (though this probably has similar issues to above).

Do ***not*** add your Python path to the `secure_path` as this will probably screw up more than a couple of standard `sudo` calls.

Comment: Calling your anaconda python binary is your safest bet.